# Kubuntu, Plasma, alternate graphics chips and multiple displays

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I'm going to start vague on this one, as I'm a bit out of my depth and would rather be guided by you guys than throw about a load of useless info.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P50 with, so it seems, more than one graphics chip.  I've connected a bunch of external displays via various means, but can't persuade my laptop to see them (kind of).  As I connected each one, I got a pop up asking what I'd like to do with it.  The same happens when I turn them off or on, so it's obviously detecting the display somewhere.  Alas, regardless what option I pick (e.g. extend to the left) the display just goes into power save with no signal.  System Settings --> Display & Monitor only shows my built in laptop display and no drop down option to select another.

Info Center shows the Graphics Processor as Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530, however when I dig into Devices --> PCI there's also an entry for NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M].

Presumably, as I'm seeing the Intel chip on the About screen, that's the one I'm using, but that doesn't tell me why the display is detected but not selectible.

Halp!  How do I make at least one of the external displays work?  If I can get one going, there's a good chance I can figure out getting more than one up & running.  I've got one connected via DVI, one via HDMI, one via VGA (I know, yuk) and a fourth through a proprietary Lenovo USB-DVI converter.  I can see that the converter is detected correctly, but if that winds up being troublesome, I'm happy to lose it.

I'm simple, so let's start simple and see how we go!